# Php7.0-fpm high load cpu

Tags: php, linux, nginx, debian

I have a bug. He arise random. working may 2-3 day is normal but after some events start high load cpu
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb7FG.png)

i do strace on php-fpm when it arise

```
    --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=695, si_uid=33, si_status=0, ...} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 707
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 823753717}) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=701, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 140034873437968
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=698, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 140034873437968
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32743
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 824399822}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 708
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 825037147}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32744
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 825227552}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=702, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 710
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 827677677}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32747
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 827886974}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 711
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 828755896}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32748
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 828921349}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 712
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 829779218}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32749
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 829951780}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = 713
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 830916994}) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 32750
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {760605, 831123550}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=707, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=708, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 10154
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f5c688b6a10) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=710, si_uid=33, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

Update kernel not resolve this problem?
Help only Restart php-fpm process
What you can me advice? Thanks

Comment: is the `apt-get upgrade` a coincidence or something you could see at those random incidents ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I do apt-get upgrade no sense, no see coincidence

Answer (score 0):

It is because your socket it is trying to do a write when he cant:

```
write(8, "C", 1)                        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigreturn()                          = 56
```

Since you don't have any means of change the source code, you need to downgrade your php version and see if it is able to complete the task without this socket issue.

See more:

[Why STRACE shows EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666145/why-strace-shows-eagain-resource-temporarily-unavailable)

Comment: what version need?